# What is the heuristic to decide number of components for LDA dimensionality reduction?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, discriminant-analysis

In the PCA case, I prefer to plot the variance and choose number of components regarding that plot's breaking point. In the LDA (linear disriminant analysis) case, what can be used for such an observation. I am using Sklearn for being specific. What value in the LDA model is valid for this selection?

Comment: You have to explain, what is correct. Why, for example, you do it in PCA the "correct" way you do it.

Comment: I rewrote the question